# Microsoft Office 2013 Crashes from Vb.net Program

Tags: vb.net, ms-office, word-automation

I have a vb.net program that the user is able to create a word file from a text file, open and edit it, and save their changes back to a web server.

When the user creates the file and uploads it everything works fine. The issue happens when they open any document. When the user is done editing and saves the file then closes out word,  Office throw a not responding message and forces them to close the office program, but when I check the document they tried to upload to the server the changes they made are present so my program is completing its process without error, I would assume.

This only happens in Microsoft Office 2013.

Below is the code I am using:

```
Private Sub oWord_DocumentBeforeClose(ByVal Doc As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document, ByRef Cancel As Boolean) Handles oWord.DocumentBeforeClose
    'Cancel = True
    Try
        oWord.ActiveDocument.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("There was an issue closing word document" & ex.ToString())
    End Try
    'oWord.Quit()
    Try
        oWord.Application.Quit()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("There was an issue closing word" & ex.ToString())
    End Try
    Try
        Dim filepath As String
        'Dim url As String = Server & "php/PD026U.php"
        Dim url As String = Server & LibName & "/PD026U.pgm"
        'Dim url As String = "http://192.168.95.1:83/file.php"
        filepath = strCommonAppData & IO.Path.GetFileName(ORGDoc)

        Dim request As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(HttpWebRequest.Create(url), HttpWebRequest)

        request.PreAuthenticate = True
        request.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = True
        request.KeepAlive = True
        request.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10

        Dim boundary As String = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString()

        request.Accept = "text/html , application/xhtml+xml, */*"
        request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip
        request.ContentType = String.Format("multipart/form-data; boundary={0}", boundary)
        request.Method = "POST"
        request.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential("ehavermale", "ernie1")

        ' Build Contents for Post
        Dim header As String = String.Format("--{0}", boundary)
        Dim footer As String = header & "--"

        Dim contents As New System.Text.StringBuilder()
        Dim FileHead As New System.Text.StringBuilder()

        ' file
        FileHead.AppendLine(header)
        FileHead.AppendLine(String.Format("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""upfile""; filename=""{0}""", IO.Path.GetFileName(filepath)))
        FileHead.AppendLine("Content-Type: application/msword")
        FileHead.AppendLine()

        contents.AppendLine(vbCrLf & header)
        contents.AppendLine("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""task""")
        contents.AppendLine()
        contents.AppendLine("upload")

        contents.AppendLine(header)
        contents.AppendLine("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""INCOMP""")
        contents.AppendLine()
        contents.AppendLine(INCOMP)

        contents.AppendLine(header)
        contents.AppendLine("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""ProgLib""")
        contents.AppendLine()
        contents.AppendLine(LibName)

        contents.AppendLine(header)
        contents.AppendLine("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""INCNUM""")
        contents.AppendLine()
        contents.AppendLine(INNUM)

        contents.AppendLine(header)
        contents.AppendLine("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""ToPath""")
        contents.AppendLine()
        contents.AppendLine(ToPath)

        ' Footer
        contents.AppendLine(footer)

        ' This is sent to the Post
        Dim bytes As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(contents.ToString())
        Dim FileBytes As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(FileHead.ToString())

        request.ContentLength = bytes.Length + FileHead.Length + New FileInfo(filepath).Length

        Using requestStream As Stream = request.GetRequestStream()
            requestStream.Write(FileBytes, 0, FileBytes.Length)
            Using fileStream As New IO.FileStream(filepath, IO.FileMode.Open, IO.FileAccess.Read)

                Dim buffer(4096) As Byte
                Dim bytesRead As Int32 = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)

                Do While (bytesRead > 0)
                    requestStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead)
                    bytesRead = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
                Loop
                fileStream.Close()
            End Using
            requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)
            requestStream.Flush()
            requestStream.Close()

            Using response As WebResponse = request.GetResponse()
                Using reader As New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
                    Dim strResponseData As String = reader.ReadToEnd()
                    TextBox1.Text = strResponseData
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("There was an Error on File Upload Please Contact you Administrator for assistance : " & ex.ToString())
    End Try

    Me.Close()
End Sub
```

I have tried changing how I close my word program, the order I close the document and word and tried to keep word open altogether and nothing I have tried works.

Is there an issue with Office 2013 and beforeclose or programmatically closing a document?

Comment: What is the exception message or stack trace?

Comment: It isn't returning one. I checked the application logs on the PC and there were no errors there either. The only message I am getting is  Microsoft has stopped responding. Then I goes through the solution process and winds up telling me none were found and to close the program.

Comment: When is it crashing? In which line?

Comment: I can't tell. My program is executing the way it should (ie. the user saves the file they are working on, then i takes that file and sends it to our servers. The file gets sent up to our server without error)

Comment: I found the line that is breaking Word it is the oWord.ActiveDocument.Close() but I need to close the document in order to upload it to our server. Is there another way to close a document that Office 2013 can handle?

Comment: If I am not mistaken, I can see you are handling the beforeclose event, which means that when you execute oWord.ActiveDocument.Close() it either try to re-close the document and get in the same event again (infinite loop, possible stack overflow? thus crashing the app) or something crazy is happening. The documentation at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb221282(v=office.12).aspx says that this event "Occurs immediately before any open document closes." Are you sure you want to close the doc again in this event?

Answer (score 0):

I found my problem. There is a COM Add-in called Send to Bluetooth that needed to be disabled now everything is working fine